# Как должно выглядеть подключение moxy с androidx?

Tags: android, moxy

Пытаюсь подключить Moxy с androidX, но пишет дубликаты классов:

```
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.DefaultView found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.DefaultViewState found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.InjectViewState found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpDelegate found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpFacade found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpPresenter found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpPresenter$Binder found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpProcessor found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpView found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.PresenterBinder found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.PresenterStore found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.PresentersCounter found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.RegisterMoxyReflectorPackages found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.ViewStateProvider found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.InjectPresenter found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.PresenterField found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.ProvidePresenter found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.ProvidePresenterTag found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.MvpViewState found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.ViewCommand found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.ViewCommands found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.AddToEndSingleStrategy found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.AddToEndStrategy found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.OneExecutionStateStrategy found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.SingleStateStrategy found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.SkipStrategy found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.StateStrategy found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)
Duplicate class com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.strategy.StateStrategyType found in modules moxy-1.5.6.jar (com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6) and moxy-x-1.7.0.jar (tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Зависимости:

```
implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.6'
implementation 'tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x-androidx:1.7.0'
implementation 'tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x-material:1.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-compiler:2.0.2'
```

Какие зависимости должны быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать смесь из свежего moxy-компилятора и устаревшие и неподдерживаемые версии самого `Moxy` и неофициального форка к нему, созданного для внедрения поддержки `androidx`.

Используйте свежую официальную версию - там есть поддержка `androidx` без необходимости сторонних форков. Смотрите свежую версию тут: https://github.com/moxy-community/Moxy

Comment: При добавлении данной библиотеки пишет ошибку: NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lru/../login/LoginActivity$$PresentersBinder$mLoginPresenterBinder;

Comment: @chilo5432, попробуйте `clean + rebuild` и дополните вопрос, показав как теперь ваши зависимости Moxy выглядят.

Comment: не помогло. Сразу это пробую.
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-app-compat:2.0.2"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-androidx:2.0.2"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-material:2.0.2"

Comment: @chilo5432, а `annotationProcessor` подключили?

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб приветствую,хотелось бы узнать, как вы определили,что это официальная версия? Спасибо

Comment: @Tony, добрый вечер) Так написано в бывшем официальном репозитории: https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy. То что бывший репозиторий официальный - знаю со слов одного из разработчиков Moxy, с коим лично знаком)

Comment: боже! я полтора дня бился головой чтобы завести moxy + dagger2, а как оказалось я юзал старую либу которая не поддерживает androidX. ответ выше "Смотрите свежую версию тут: https://github.com/moxy-community/Moxy" решил мою проблему с ходу с лету, правда перелопатить все анотации пришлось и импорты в классах переписать. начало хорошее) дружелюбненько)